# jquery drop down box font and alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on this site:  http://gitastudents.com/~clarkb/group1/Students.html

main css here: http://gitastudents.com/~clarkb/group1/style.css

I am unable to change the font color and size on the drop downs.
I would like the font to be white not the green that is on the rest of the page.
It seems that it is something in the css that isnt set up right but i can't figure out what it is.

Also i would like the drop downs to be centered in their respective boxes but i cant get that to work either.

Thank you in advance!

---

Bryan

Comment: Have you considered changing your question title to: "I need you to debug 406 lines of code for me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably having trouble doing it because you need to target those very specifically. The following CSS rule should work:

```
a.ui-selectmenu span{
 color:#ffffff;
}
```

As for centering the dropdowns, you could use:

```
fieldset{
  text-align:center;
}
```

I would suggest, however, that you give those fieldset's a class and target the class.

I just noticed that you have the dropdowns wrapped in a div...you could modify that div (the one with the class dropdown) giving it a specific width (240px ish) and that should center them (since you've already applied margin: auto to that class).

Comment: How can I vertically align the boxes too?
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-top:auto;
height:100px;

i put that in the div and i didn't work like the horizontal did.

Comment: There are a couple ways:
1) Use a table and use vertical-align:middle;. 2) Change the containing div (class entryMini) to have display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle;. Check out this link for a more detailed explanation: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html